# how to give dynamic height to elements

Tags: javascript, php

I've an array with following fields name and count.

I would like to give dynamic height and width depending upon the count of array with PHP or Javascript.

I've predefine maximum and minimum height also so just need a function which can return height for all.

For example my array is :

```
$arr = array(
    array('name'=>'a','count'=>'2'),
    array('name'=>'b','count'=>'3'),
    array('name'=>'c','count'=>'1'),
    array('name'=>'d','count'=>'2')
);

a - 2
b - 3
c - 1
d - 2
```

Let's assume my min. height is 110 and max. height is 150

so c is smallest so its height will be 110
and b is largest so its height will be 150

and a and d have same value so should be same height as 130 between both

and it should be dynamic so can work for any no. of count and any no. variables.

How can I do all this with 1 function ?

Please suggest some link or something

Comment: What function have you created so far for this purpose?

Comment: I'm searching I need a way to do it rest I'll make function I want to know the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code calculate height on base of value of count item

```
$arr = array(
    array('name'=>'a','count'=>'2'),
    array('name'=>'b','count'=>'3'),
    array('name'=>'c','count'=>'1'),
    array('name'=>'d','count'=>'2')
);

$cnt = array_column($arr, 'count');

$cnt_min = min($cnt);
$cnt_max = max($cnt);
$min = 110;
$max = 150;

foreach($arr as &$item) 
   $item['heaight'] = $min + floor(($item['count']-$cnt_min)*($max-$min)/($cnt_max-$cnt_min));

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the desired height according to your description
`$height = (110 + ($arr["a"]["count"] * 10))."px";`
Then you can use either way you know to populate your html, like just adding an inline style when you `echo` it:
`<div class = "yourClass" style = "height:'.$height.';"></div>`